# Why am I getting a list index out of range error?

Tags: python

I'm not sure why I am getting the following error:

```
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

at the following line (line 5):

```
C[A[key(a)]] == C[A[key(a)]] + 1
```

An example of input for this code would be `A = [2, -2, 1]` and `key = lambda x: x**2`, and in the loop on line 4-5, it takes the key of item at `A[a]` as the chosen index for array `C`, and increments the value at that index by `1`. For example: `C[A[key(0)]]`, or `C[4]`, is `0`, and it is incremented to `1`.

```
def key_positions(A, key):
    k = key(max(A, key = key))
    C = [0] * (k+1)
    for a in A:
        C[A[key(a)]] == C[A[key(a)]] + 1
    for i in range(0, k):
        sum = C[i]
    return C
```

Comment: More to the point, what is that line supposed to *do*? You're making a comparison, but not assigning the result. Did you mean assignment (`=`, not `==`)?

Comment: Even with just =, I get the same error.

Comment: Well, yes; the key error happens before either comparison or assignment. But think about the case of `A == [2, -2, 1]`, when `a == 2`. What is `A[4]`? Either write out your example on paper or use e.g. http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html to step through it.

Comment: Why `A[key(a)]`? `a` is one value in `A`, not an index. `key(a)` is going to be even further out of range, as `x**2` is not an index either.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to treat `key(a)` as an index into the list `A`. Neither `a` nor `key(a)` are valid indices in the range `[0, len(A)]`.

If you wanted to count occurrences of `key(a)`, *just use that directly* as an index into `C`:

```
def key_positions(A, key):
    k = key(max(A, key = key))
    C = [0] * (k+1)
    for a in A:
        C[key(a)] += 1
    for i in range(0, k):
        sum = C[i]
    return C
```

I used `+=` augmented assignment here rather than the more verbose `C[key(a)] = C[key(a)] + 1`; this saves re-executing the `key()` function each time.

Calculating the maximum `k` value is also simpler with:

```
k = max(key(a) for a in A)
```

Next, your loop with `sum = C[i]` is also nonsensical; the loop is redundant as you don't ever use `sum` and you could have used `sum = C[-1]` for all that the loop does.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you access the List A = [2, -2, 1]  with a index that is out of bounds of your list A.

For every iteration of your first for loop,
you calculates the square of a (through your key lamba) and this leads to the index error.

You have to make sure that you don't access the list A with index values that are bigger than the size of the List A.

For example:

```
for a in A: 
  # key(a) will be 4, 4, 1
  # but for key(2) it will be 4
  # and larger than the list A.
  C[A[key(a)]] == C[A[key(a)]] + 1
```